# Control the height of custom scroll bar

Tags: html, css, custom-scrolling

I have created a custom horizontal scroll. I added the snippet with this code.

The problem occurred is it adjusts it's height according to the section height.

What I want is, no matter what is the height of the section, I want to keep the scroll bar with fixed height. No need of responsive. I can write media queries when I get a solution.

**Please Note**

> This height habit happens not only happening when customizing, It
>   seems like the default behavior. I want control it.

```css
.scrollbar_sec {
  margin-left: 22px;
  float: left;
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.row h2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.row p {
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px;
}

.scrollbar_sec::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar_sec::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}

.scrollbar_sec::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <h2>This is a section with less content</h2>
      <p>Scroll bar height is normal</p>
      <!--content-->
      <div class="scrollbar_sec">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <h2>This is a section with More content</h2>
      <p>Now you can see the scrollbar height is gone small when the content is gone high</p>
      <!--content-->
      <div class="scrollbar_sec">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
        qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not gonna be achievable with your approach. You are very limited with what you can do with scrollbars. Chrome/Webkit is one of the few that allows you to change them a little bit. When you check on Firefox you can barely change them (or not at all, im not certain)

Comment: @zeropublix Thank you for you're reply. I know only `-webkit-`  allows to customize scrollbars when `-moz-` and `-ms-` doesn't. But still In want it to be done in `-webkit-`. There are few features. Are you sure that there are no features to control the height. I am asking this because I couldn't find any article or a single comment about this issue.

Comment: you cannot fix the scrollbar height. it depends on you browser and you content and change accordingly.

Comment: Although you can change it's width radius all but not the height